# How to I put time in my website's tab?

Tags: time, tags, title

I was wondering if any of you can tell me how I can put the time in my website's tab. Heres an example: http://blog.wearebuild.com/

As you can see on the top (where the title is), it says "Build - We do Print - 22.10"

I am using DreamWeaver to design this website.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript to modify `document.title` to dynamically alter the [page's title](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_title.asp). If you want to insert the date/time you can use [JavaScript's Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that, Im pretty new at this :/ would you mind going into detail please?

Comment: You would put `<script type="text/javascript">document.title = new Date(); </script>` in the <head> section of your html. If you want it to constantly update, that would require a bit more work with looping.